# Merge or Union a list of dynamically created querysets - Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a list of querysets as follows. Is there a way to merge all these query sets of a list into one query set ? The queryset elements of this list are dynamically determined. As in the example below it is three querysets in the list. In next hypothetical iteration it could be 40 querysets.

```
capture_list =[<QuerySet [<Fields_Model: Fields_Model object (11)>]>,<QuerySet [<Fields_Model: Fields_Model object (12)>]>,<QuerySet [<Fields_Model: Fields_Model object (13)>]>]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can union these with:

```
Fields_Model.objects.none().union(*capture_list)
```

Here the asterisk will thus "unpack" the querysets as individual parameters for the [**`.union(…)`** call [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#union).

A call with `.union(…)` will only select *distinct* objects, so no duplicates. If you want to obtain the duplicates, you can the **`all=True`** parameter:

```
Fields_Model.objects.none().union(*capture_list, all=True)
```